# Given the fundamental theorem of calculus part 1, prove the part 2

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given:
$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $g$ defined by:
$g(x) = \int _a^xf\left(t\right)dt
$
is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $g'(x) = f(x)$

Prove that:
$\int _a^bf\left(x\right)dx = F(b)-F(a)
$

Comment: Also, what is the function $F(x)$? Is that an antiderivative of $f $?

Comment: Do you mean g (b)-g (a) instead of F (b)-F (a)?

Comment: Um, what is F?  By definition int from a to b is g (b).  And it's easy to to see g (a) = 0.  So I assume there is more to the question then proving int is g (b)-g (a).

Answer (score 0):

See that we have, given $f(x)$ is continuous and that for some unknown continuous function $F(x)$,

$$\frac d{dx}\left(\int_a^xf(t)dt-[F(x)-F(a)]\right)=f(x)-F'(x)=0$$

Since the derivative of the integral is taken care of by the FTOC Part I, and we are trying to find the function $F(x)$ that satisfies this.  It is then trivial to see that if we must have $F'(x)=f(x)$, then $F(x)$ is, by definition, the antiderivative of $f(x)$.

Thus,

$$\int_a^xf(t)dt-[F(x)-F(a)]=c\ \forall\ (x,a)\in\mathbb R$$

for an unknown constant $c$, since the only function with $0$ as it's derivative for all $x$ is a constant function.  By having $x=a$, you can see that $c=0$, thus, we have

$$\int_a^xf(t)dt-[F(x)-F(a)]=0$$

> $$\int_a^xf(t)dt=F(x)-F(a)$$